# Excel Sum by Month

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sum

Hi have the following scenario:

Items in Column A, Total Time in Column B, then I have 365 dates in columns.

[image]

I want to summarise the column dates by month.

I want, for example, for Item A, in March, total Times taken.
How to do it?
Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of the Time column? Are the values not represented in the date columns?

Comment: This is only 12 months. Do you really need any form of automation for this? Why don't you insert `SUM` functions manually for first row and then autofill it for remaining rows?

Comment: It is a key for the duration of an item. I see.

Comment: Just insert `=SUM(C2:AG2)` for January.

Comment: You can make a table with sums manually and then add some automated form of presenting it to the user/client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, somewhat overkill but was interested in how to do it with power query and was interested in building a custom function for the MonthNumber.

*Powerquery is free add-in for pre 2016 and is inbuilt for 2016*

**STEPS**:

1) Data tab (2016) or powerquery tab (2010 to 2016) => Select `query from table` and ensure your source data is selected and appears in pop-up

[image: Selecting data]

[image: Query from table window]

2) Select the first date column, hold shift down and select last date, then select unpivot columns

[image: Unpivot all date columns]

3) Make sure column Attribute (your pivoted dates) is formatted as a date column

[image: Format date column]

4) Open the advanced query editor window

[image: Opening advanced query editor]

and paste the following between `let` and `source`

```
fnMonthNum = (input) => let
values = {
{"January", "1"},
{"February", "2"},
{"March", "3"},
{"April","4"},
{"May", "5"},
{"June", "6"},
{"July", "7"},
{"August", "8"},
{"September", "9"},
{"October", "10"},
{"November", "11"},
{"December", "12"},
{input, "Undefined"}

},
Result = List.First(List.Select(values, each _{0}=input)){1}
in
Result,
```

This is M code for creating a custom function that returns month numbers from month names.

[image: Adding custom function code in query editor window]

5) Add column tab => Add custom column, rename it MonthName and insert the following text

```
=Date.ToText([Attribute],"MMMM")
```

[image: Adding MonthName formula]

6) Add another custom column, rename it MonthNum and use our new function here:

```
= fnMonthNum([MonthName])
```

[image: Using custom function to return Month Number from Month Name]

7) Remove the now unnecessary Attribute column; select column => right click => remove

[image: Remove attribute column]

8) Transform tab => Group by and enter the following:

[image: Grouping options]

9) Make sure MonthNum column is numeric.

[image: Converting MonthNum column to numeric]

10)  Close and load to => `Only create connection`, 
     Tick checkbox for `Add to data model`, and then `Load`

[image: Load option - connection only, add to data model]

11) As per instructions here: [CREATE A PIVOT TABLE USING EXCEL’S INTERNAL DATA MODEL](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/create-pivot-table-using-excels-internal-data-model/)

Choose `Insert→PivotTable` from the Ribbon. The Create PivotTable dialog box opens.

[image: Creating pivottable from our query]

Select the Use an `External Data Source` option, as shown, and then click the `Choose Connection` button. You see the Existing Connections dialog box, as shown.

Select the query you just created for Table1 and a destination for the pivottable

[image: Selecting destination for pivottable]

12) Arrange the fields as required and sort ascending on the MonthNum rowfield

[image: Arrange pivottable]

13) Insert slicer

[image: Slicer insert]

Note: You could introduce a custom sort to avoid having to use the MonthNum column for sorting.